# Iterating through Yaml file with many arrays (python)

Tags: python, list, loops, yaml

I have the following yaml file:

```
name: Tiger
points: [100, 5000]
calls: [1, 10]
```

which I load into python via

```
with open("myfile.yaml") as f:
    myfile = yaml.safe_load(f)
```

What I want is to write code that automatically calls some function with every combination of values from the yaml file like this:

```
my_function(Tiger, 100, 1)
my_function(Tiger, 100, 10)
my_function(Tiger, 5000, 1)
my_function(Tiger, 5000, 10)
```

I know I could use loops like this:

```
for item1 in myfile["points"]:
    for item2 in myfile["calls"]:
        my_function(Tiger, item1, item2)
```

but my yaml file in fact has many such arrays, not just "points" and "calls" but a hundred other arrays (which may have different number of elements in the arrays, not all the same). So I want to do it in some more elegant way instead of writing a bunch of nested `for` statements. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create combinations with **product** function.

**Product function:** Cartesian product of input iterables. Equivalent to nested for-loops.

**Sample Code:**

```
import yaml
from itertools import product

with open("test.yaml") as f:
    myfile = yaml.safe_load(f)

arrays_to_iterate = [myfile["points"], myfile["calls"]]  

# get all possible combinations
combinations = list(product(*arrays_to_iterate))

# sample function implementation here, now only prints the parameters
def my_function(name, *args):
    print(name, *args)
    
for combination in combinations:
    my_function(myfile["name"], *combination)
```

**YAML File (test.yaml):**

```
name: Tiger
points: [100, 5000]
calls: [1, 10]
```

**Output:**

[image]